# Using GetVstoObject and HasVstoObject

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

I have a console app that creates an excel worksheet using the Interop Library, and then tries to get the vstoObject using the GetVstoObject to use the  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel Library. When running the code below the HasVstoObject always returns false, not sure if it is not created yet when executing since this is being runned from a simple console app main program. From the documentation of Extensions it seems plausible that this can be done

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet newSheet = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet XLsWorkSheet = null;

    excelApp = new Interop.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = true;
    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    sheets = workbook.Sheets;

    newSheet = (Interop.Worksheet)sheets.Add(sheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    newSheet.Name = "My New Sheet";
    newSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "BOO!";

    if (Excel.Extensions.WorksheetExtensions.HasVstoObject(newSheet)) {
       XLsWorkSheet = Excel.Extensions.WorksheetExtensions.GetVstoObject(newSheet);
       Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.ComboBox combobox1 = XLsWorkSheet.Controls.AddComboBox(XLsWorkSheet.Range["A1", "A1"], "combobox1");
       combobox1.Items.Add("1 Item");
        }
```

I also created a Excel 2007 addin to try this and it dosent work when using Globals.Factory.GetvstoObject
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that `HasVstoObject` will always return false if you never have called `GetVstoObject` to "cache" the extended VSTO-Object. So the solution is to call `GetVstoObject` without the enclosing `if` and everything will work fine. After that, the method `HasVstoObject` will also return `true`.

Regards,
Jörg

P.S.: I also don't really understand the deeper sense of the `HasVstoObject` method...